# finding perfect squares solutions for the following case

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, square-numbers

I was working on a number theory problem and create a equation. I tried research on this, but tbh I don't even know what should I google for... Here's my cases.

$$n = \sqrt{N *  \frac{1+\sqrt{4k^2+1}}{2}}$$
$$m = \sqrt{N *  \frac{\sqrt{4k^2+1}-1}{2}}$$

Where N is a given integer, m, n are both unknown integers, k has a given range of [0, 10] and k is a real number.

My question is, What is the fastest way to find such k that create integers m and n?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you expect the answer(s) to be unique?  With $N=1$, for instance, then $k=2\sqrt 3$ works as does $k=6\sqrt 2$

Comment: @lulu Ohh it doesn't have to be unique, should I change the 'n is an unknown integer' into 'unknown integers?

Comment: Your header refers to "unique" solutions, but maybe you meant something else?

Comment: @lulu just changed that, thanks for that.

Comment: In any case:  for a fixed $N$, I'd compute the expression with $k=\frac 89$, and compute it for $k=9$.  Then, for each integer between the two values you get you can easily find a solution $k$ that gives you that integer.

Comment: @CarlChristian Is there a well known property that I could apply on this?

Comment: @lulu let me try that real quick!

Comment: @lulu I just tried what u said and it works fairly well, but then I realized that I wasn't post the whole picture up there, so could you check my update please?

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for your advice! I just removed that word and plot the graph as well, it make more sense now!

Comment: Do you need to get integers $m,n$ for the same $k$?  My answer predates the request for $m$, but the same approach works.  If you need integers for the same $k$, note that the radicands differ by $N$ so you need two perfect squares that differ by $N$.  Then write $n^2-m^2=N=(n+m)(n-m)$ and use the ways to factor $N$ into two factors.

Comment: Yes, same k will be applied for m and n, I see your point! but how can I find two perfect squares or two factors? like is there any potential approach on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the range in $k$, you have $$1+\frac {\sqrt{337}}{18} \le \frac {1+\sqrt{1+4k^2}}2\le 1+\frac {5\sqrt{13}}2$$
The left side is a little more than $2$ and the right a little more than $10$.  The range of $n$ that is available is from $\left\lceil\sqrt{\left(1+\frac {\sqrt{337}}{18}\right)N}\right\rceil$ to $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\left(1+\frac {5\sqrt{13}}2\right)N}\right\rfloor$ inclusive.  Choose your $n$ and solve the equation for $k$.

For your new problem with $m,n$, note that the radicands differ by $N$, so we can write $n^2-m^2=N=(n+m)(n-m)$.  The two factors $n+m$ and $n-m$ have the same parity, so if $N$ is divisible by $2$ and not $4$ there is no solution.  Otherwise, each way of factoring $N$ into two factors of the same parity give a solution to $n=\sqrt {aN+\frac N2}, m=\sqrt{aN-\frac N2}$.  For each factorization, you can see if $a$ is in the range at the top of my post.  If it is, $k$ will be in range, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: I just updated my problem since I realized that I wasn't described my problem well enough, sorry about that, could you check the update please?

Comment: Hey Ross! Thanks for the update!! the last formula involvong a is great, but I'm kinda wondering how did u get that. could you please explain that to me as well?

Comment: It is just the standard factoring of the difference of squares.  You can multiply it out to see it works.  For example, if $N=24=2^33$ we can have $n+m=12,n-m=2,n=7,m=5, n^2-m^2=49-25=24$ or $n+m=5,n-m=4,n=5,m=1,n^2-m^2=5^2-1^2=24$

Comment: If you are doing number theory this factorization should be the first thing you think of when you see the difference of squares.  It comes up all the time.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, I'm just getting started with number theory and thanks for the important tip! I think I understand the part to set up m+n and m-n and solve the system of equations, but I'm also a little bit lost when you did $n = \sqrt{aN + \frac{N}2}$, could you explain that to me please?

Comment: I should have defined $a=\frac 12\sqrt{4k^2+1}$.  I just did it to save typing, but forgot to state the definition.